# How can I get only one line of error description from Try/Catch block?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to only get the one-line description of the error message in the below code when the destination URL in the Array of Strings is not reachable or having some other issue.

```
Clear-Host
$serverName = 'bong.com', 'bing.com', 'hotel.com', 'hotels.com'
$statusCodesAllowed = (200, 302, 401) #Update this array to include the HTTP status codes that you want to mark as OK.$stat = 0

Foreach ($URL in $serverName) {
    Try {
        $web = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://$url -Method Head -UseDefaultCredentials -UseBasicParsing -ErrorAction Stop
        $stat = [int]($statusCodesAllowed -contains $web.statusCode)
        Write-Host "`nURL: $(($URL -split '/')[0]) - $([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses(($URL -split '/')[0]))" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        Write-Host 'Statistic.Status: '$stat -ForegroundColor Green
        Write-Host 'Message.Status: ' $web.StatusCode $web.StatusDescription -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    
    Catch {
        $statusCode = ($_.Exception.Message.Substring(($_.Exception.Message.IndexOf('(') + 1), 3))
        $stat = [int]($statusCodesAllowed -contains $statusCode)
        Write-Host "`nURL: $(($URL -split '/')[0]) - $([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses(($URL -split '/')[0]))" -ForegroundColor Red
        Write-Warning -Message "Error in resolving $URL"
        Write-Warning 'Message.Status: '$_.Exception.Message -Verbose
    }
    Finally { Remove-Variable serverName, statusCodesAllowed, stat, web, statusCode -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue }
}
```

The expected result is like below. Place the working URL on top and the URL contains error result at the bottom.

```
URL: bing.com - 13.107.21.200 204.79.197.200
Statistic.Status:  1
Message.Status:  200 OK


URL: bong.com - 195.42.193.61
WARNING: Error in resolving bong.com
   'The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.'.


URL: hotel.com - 204.74.99.101
WARNING: Error in resolving hotel.com
   'Unable to connect to the remote server'.
 
URL: hotels.com - 104.98.28.184
WARNING: Error in resolving hotels.com
   'The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.'.
```

I do not need the error details on the source code.

Comment: Construct your output as a hash table or PSCustomObject for output formatting.

Comment: @postanote, yes, I wonder if you can assist me with that example?

Comment: What if you just change it to `Write-Warning "Message.Status: $_" -Verbose`

Comment: man, you are correct. thank you for the assistance in this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mia culpa for the late response, but, you know, stuff.

To get the layout/colorization you show in your post, even without PSCustomerObject (as @Scepticalist shows, which is more elegant and useable especially for sending to a file/csv report/Excel, etc.), you could just do this.

```
Clear-Host
$serverName = 'bong.com', 'bing.com', 'hotel.com', 'hotels.com' 
Foreach ($URL in $serverName) 
{
    $statusCodesAllowed = (200, 302, 401)
    Try 
    {
        $web            = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://$url -Method Head -UseDefaultCredentials -UseBasicParsing -ErrorAction Stop
        $stat           = [int]($statusCodesAllowed -contains $web.statusCode)
        $HostName       = Write-Host "`nURL: $(($URL -split '/')[0]) - $([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses(($URL -split '/')[0]))" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        $HostStatistics = Write-Host 'Statistic.Status: '$stat -ForegroundColor Green
        $HostStatus     = Write-Host 'Message.Status: ' $web.StatusCode $web.StatusDescription -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    
    Catch 
    {
        $statusCode   = ($_.Exception.Message.Substring(($PSItem.Exception.Message.IndexOf('(') + 1), 3))
        $stat         = [int]($statusCodesAllowed -contains $statusCode)
        $HostName     = Write-Host "`nURL: $(($URL -split '/')[0]) - $([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses(($URL -split '/')[0]))" -ForegroundColor Red
        $ErrorMessage = Write-Warning -Message "Error in resolving $URL `n`tMessage.Status: $($PSItem.Exception.Message)" -Verbose
    }
    Finally 
    { 
           Remove-Variable serverName, statusCodesAllowed, stat, web, statusCode, 
           Hostname, HostStatistics, HostStatus, 
           ErrorMessage -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
    }
}

# Results
<#
URL: bong.com - 195.42.193.61
WARNING: Error in resolving bong.com 
    Message.Status: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

URL: bing.com - 2620:1ec:c11::200 204.79.197.200 13.107.21.200
Statistic.Status:  1
Message.Status:  200 OK

URL: hotel.com - 204.74.99.101
WARNING: Error in resolving hotel.com 
    Message.Status: Unable to connect to the remote server

URL: hotels.com - 23.62.70.63
WARNING: Error in resolving hotels.com 
    Message.Status: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
#>
```

Comment: Thanks @postanote. this is very great.
I appreciate your assistance in this matter.

Comment: No worries, glad to assist. PowerShell always has ways to do X or Y and that's a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
Clear-Host
$serverName = 'bong.com', 'bing.com', 'hotel.com', 'hotels.com'
$statusCodesAllowed = (200, 302, 401) #Update this array to include the HTTP status codes that you want to mark as OK.$stat = 0

$URLarray = $serverName | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "Processing:" $_
    Try {
        $web = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://$_ -Method Head -UseDefaultCredentials -UseBasicParsing -ErrorAction Stop
        $stat = [int]($statusCodesAllowed -contains $web.statusCode)
        $IPs = $([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses(($_ -split '/')[0]))
        $StatusCode = $web.StatusCode
        $StatusDesc = $web.StatusDescription
    }
    Catch {
        $statusCode = ($_.Exception.Message.Substring(($_.Exception.Message.IndexOf('(') + 1), 3))
        $stat = [int]($statusCodesAllowed -contains $statusCode)
        $IPs = $([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses(($URL -split '/')[0]))
        $StatusCode = "Error"
        $StatusDesc = $_.Exception.Message
    }
    [pscustomobject]@{URL=$_;IPs=$IPs;Status=$StatusCode;StatusDetail=$StatusDesc}
}

$URLarray
```

All you results are in $URLarray - you can output/format as you wish e.g.

```
$URLarray | Sort-Object Status | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "`nURL:"$_.URL" - " $_.IPs -ForegroundColor Yellow
    If ($_.Status -ne "Error") {
        Write-Host $_.Status -ForegroundColor Green
        Write-Host $_.StatusDetail -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    Else {
        Write-Host "Error:"  $_.StatusDetail -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow @scepticalist, that's so cool. yes, thank you so much for the assistance.